# How to track events or e-commerce sales that occur later using Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, ecommerce

Here's my problem:

- I have a static site with Google Analytics tracking code.
- To buy one of my services, users call me, and when their order is ready (many days later), I send them an e-mail link to a special page (download.php) where I have GA tracking code that is executed the first time they visit, so I track a "sale".
- The issue is, GA thinks that "sale" was a separate visit, and erroneously shows that only direct visits to my site result in sales. I don't understand how I can view stats (Pages / Visit, Avg. Time on Site, etc.) about users who eventually bought something.

I've tried events and e-commerce tracking with no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Anton, what you need to do is to check the [Multi Channel Funnel](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/features/multichannel-funnels.html) subsection, and the Top Converting Path report.

You also need to [code your URLs with utm parameters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867) when you email your payment link to the customer. This way your visits will start reporting email (or whichever medium you choose) when you send them the payment link instead of the direct traffic source.

In the multi channel funnel, you would want to find out which traffic source gets you the highest visitor acquisitions.

Comment: Multi Channel Funnel link is broken